# Grunt integration with Jenkins on windows issue

Tags: jenkins, gruntjs

I am running Jenkins on Tomcat7 - Windows 7. I have provided the node bin path in my jenkins configuration. Then running a shell script as follows:

```
echo $PATH
node --version
npm install -g grunt-cli
npm install
grunt cssmin
```

As suggested in other post [Jenkins integration with Grunt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21765428/jenkins-integration-with-grunt), I have restarted my jenkins several times, and tried to work on all the answers written in that post, but still it shows error, grunt: command not found.

Error stack trace from jenkins console output:

```
/c/apache-maven-3.2.5/bin:/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_79/bin:/c/Program Files/nodejs/bin:/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_79/bin:/c/Program Files/nodejs/:

+ node --version
v0.10.30
+ npm install -g grunt-cli
C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm\grunt -> C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\grunt-cli\bin\grunt
grunt-cli@0.1.13 C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\grunt-cli
â”œâ”€â”€ resolve@0.3.1
â”œâ”€â”€ nopt@1.0.10 (abbrev@1.0.7)
â””â”€â”€ findup-sync@0.1.3 (lodash@2.4.2, glob@3.2.11)
+ npm install
npm WARN package.json Trademust@1.0.0 No repository field.
+ grunt cssmin
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\temp\hudson2968878175697925824.sh: line 6: grunt: command not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I have also followed the steps mentioned on this site [grunt-on-jenkins](http://sideroad.secret.jp/articles/grunt-on-jenkins/)

package.json and Gruntfile.js are in root directory the very first time when I executed the jenkins build, grunt installed all modules from my gruntfile.js, and after that in all other build's its showing the above output.

Can anyone please check what's going on wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching a lot, I found where my grunt is installed. As far as jenkins build is concerned it installs in `drive:/.jenkins....../workspace/node_modules/.bin`.

After providing this path in jenkins using shell script `export path=$PATH:drive:/.jenkins....../workspace/node_modules/.bin`, grunt started executing.

Also what I learnt in this process was checking where the executable's are available on system path or which path jenkins refers to is using `which "executable_name"` without qoutes. you can use this command both on windows as well as linux. Ex: `which grunt` will show the path where grunt executable file is present.

Answer (score 0):

From the error message it seems, sheel is not able to find grunt. Could you please check if it is present in the $PATH variable. On which node this shell script is running? You cab check the $PATH of the particular node. You can also add grunt installation path to $PATH variable during the shell script.

```
grunt_path="grunt_installtion_path"
export PATH=${PATH}:${grunt_path}
```

Comment: It is not present on the path variable, cause grunt is not installed globally, but locally for every project. Its not available even on my local system env variable, but still I can perform all tasks with grunt in my specific project.

Comment: I have edited and included the env path in my question.

Comment: Where can I find the grunt_path, since I ran npm install in my project folder.